# Ethernet cable overheating

Tags: ethernet

I reconnected my computer yesterday after moving into a new home. Last night I couldn't get online so I decided to check my connections. My ethernet cable, where it plugged in to my Versalink 7500 Gateway, was extremely hot. The cable felt like it was on the verge of melting. The cable I used came with the gateway and it had the standard ethernet connector on one end and the other end had both ethernet and USB options. I realized that I had plugged both into my computer. Could that have caused the overheating at the other end of the cable?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have a POE cable with some sort of extra USB connector. POE (power over ethernet). It may also be that the USB cable is meant to power an ethernet device plugged into the other end of the cable, possibly causing the overheating.

If you're simply using the cable to connect to your router, I'd recommend purchasing a normal ethernet cable with no added USB connections.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what POE meant, as I'm obviously not very computer savvy lol. What you say makes sense, but I can't figure out why Verizon (my ISP) would give me that kind of cable with the router, you know? I'll try another cable today. I just wondered if it was something obvious (to people who know computers.)

Comment: it may also be that that cable allows you to connect your Gateway to your computer using either Ethernet or USB, since the Gateway is a modem and router in one.

Comment: Yes, good point. Either way, personally, I'd go with a normal CAT-5 ethernet cable.

Comment: Throw that cable out. Seriously.

Comment: specifically, that this sounds like a non-standard POE implementation; it sounds like two pairs were used for 100BaseT, and the other two pairs were directly connected to +5V and GND. Real POE doesn't have special "POE Cables", and won't short out if the device doesn't support it.